# Move variables to one side of equation

Tags: string-manipulation, algebra

I have a bunch of linear equations of the form

```
x[1] == 5012 - 5x[3] - 2x[4] + 5x[7]
```

etc. Specifically there is *one* linear variable on the left, and the right-hand side is linear (generically with a constant).

I want to process these so that all the variables come on the left and the constant stays on the right. So for the above I would want

```
x[1] + 5x[3] + 2x[4] - 5x[7] == 5012
```

as the output. This feels like a very simple thing to try and do but I am struggling to implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
eq = x[1] == 5012 - 5 x[3] - 2 x[4] + 5 x[7]
expr = eq /. Equal -> Subtract;
const = expr /. Map[# -> 0 &,  Variables[expr]]
neweq=expr - const == -const 
(*x[1] + 5 x[3] + 2 x[4] - 5 x[7] == 5012*)
```

Comment: Thank you -- this does just what I needed

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 7):

```
tran = SubtractSides[SubtractSides[#], First@CoefficientArrays[#]] &;
```

```
eqn=x[1] == 5012 - 5x[3] - 2x[4] + 5x[7];
tran[eqn]
```

> `x[1] + 5 x[3] + 2 x[4] - 5 x[7] == 5012`

```
eqns = {x[1] == 5012 - 5 x[3] - 2 x[4] + 5 x[7], 
  x[1] + 2 x[4] == -5 x[3] + 5 x[7] + 5012, 
  5012 == x[1] + 5 x[3] + 2 x[4] - 5 x[7]};
tran/@eqns
```

> `{x[1] + 5 x[3] + 2 x[4] - 5 x[7] == 5012,  x[1] + 5 x[3] + 2 x[4] - 5 x[7] ==  5012, -x[1] - 5 x[3] - 2 x[4] + 5 x[7] == -5012}`

Answer (score 3):

```
eq = x[1] == 5012 - 5 x[3] - 2 x[4] + 5 x[7]
vars = Variables[Subtract @@ eq]
ca = CoefficientArrays[eq] // Normal
vars .  Last[ca] == First@ca
```

> x[1] + 5 x[3] + 2 x[4] - 5 x[7] == -5012

Answer (score 2):

Here is yet another way.  Check if the expression is of type Plus or not. If type Plus, loop over each term and move those to the right that do not depend on the variable. If not type Plus, do nothing.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
adjust[eq_Equal] := Module[{expr, vars, lhs = 0, rhs = 0, n},
  expr = First@SubtractSides[eq];
  vars = Variables[expr];
  If[Head[expr] === Plus,
   Do[
    If[Internal`DependsOnQ[expr[[n]], vars],
     lhs = lhs + expr[[n]]
     ,
     rhs = rhs - expr[[n]]
     ]
    ,
    {n, 1, Length@expr}
    ];
   lhs == rhs
   ,
   expr == 0
   ]
  ]
```

Now

```
 adjust[x[1] == 5012 - 5 x[3] - 2 x[4] + 5 x[7]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
adjust[x[1] + 34 + y + z == -300]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
adjust[x[1] + 34 == -300 + Log[z] - Pi/2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]